# JavaScript right click context menus for different objects on a single canvas

Tags: javascript, jquery, canvas, contextmenu

I am looking for a context menu library.

I have drawn some 2d objects on a canvas: [objects](http://jsfiddle.net/younyzhU/a25Jt/3/)

```
  ctx.save();
  ctx.fillStyle = "#00ff00";
  ctx.fillRect(30, 30, 20, 20);
  ctx.stroke();
  ctx.restore();

  ctx.save();
  ctx.fillStyle = "#ff0000";
  ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 20, 20);
  ctx.stroke();
  ctx.restore();
```

I need to add a right-click context menu for control.

For example:

If I right click the red rectangle, it will show a menu: show red, or move it.
If I right click the green rectangle it shows another rectangle.
And also all the objects are movable, so if the red rectangle is moved to a different place, when I right click this object, it should show the same context menu.

**Different moveable objects on canvas show different context menu.**

**Is there some library that exists for this type of function?**
**If not, how can I try to code one?**

I found a cool library for [jquery right click context menu](http://medialize.github.io/jQuery-contextMenu/). 
But it does not meet my requirements.  It needed to bind to a certain html element to show a context menu.  In my case, I just have one element that is a canvas, and the event is triggered according to the object and position.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can handle right-clicks by listening for `contextmenu` events on the canvas:

```
// listen for contextmenu requests
canvas.addEventListener('contextmenu', handleMouseDown, false);
```

Here's an example that alerts differently for 2 different canvas rectangles:

```js
var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");

var canvasOffset=$("#canvas").offset();
var offsetX=canvasOffset.left;
var offsetY=canvasOffset.top;

var rects=[];

rects.push({x:50,y:50,width:50,height:50,color:"red"});
rects.push({x:150,y:100,width:75,height:75,color:"blue"});

ctx.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
for(var i=0;i<rects.length;i++){
  var rect=rects[i];
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.fillStyle=rect.color;
  ctx.rect(rect.x,rect.y,rect.width,rect.height);
  ctx.fill();
}

// listen for contextmenu requests
canvas.addEventListener('contextmenu', handleMouseDown, false);  

function handleMouseDown(e){

  // get mouse position relative to the canvas
  var x=parseInt(e.clientX-offsetX);
  var y=parseInt(e.clientY-offsetY);


  // check each rect for hits
  for(var i=0;i<rects.length;i++){
    var rect=rects[i];
    var rectRight=rect.x+rect.width;
    var rectBottom=rect.y+rect.height;

    // check each rect for hits
    if(x>=rect.x && x<=rectRight && y>=rect.y && y<=rectBottom  ){
      alert("Context menu request on the "+rect.color+" rectangle.");
    }
  }

  // prevents the usual context from popping up
  e.preventDefault()
  return(false); 
}
```

```css
body{ background-color: ivory; }
canvas{border:1px solid red;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h4>Right click in either rectangle.</h4>
<canvas id="canvas" width=300 height=300></canvas>
```

Comment: thanks, so all the context menu for the functional operation should be bind to a single handleMouseDown? And How add defferent types of menu?

Comment: Yes, all context menu requests are handled by listening for the 'contextmenu' event--that's because there is only 1 element firing events (the canvas).  Within that 1 handler you hit-test each rectangle and respond accordingly.  As far as different types of menus--that's up to you and your design requirements. Good luck with your project!

Comment: What is `offsetX` and `offsetY`?

Comment: @AustinCapobianco The offsets are the width and height that the canvas is away from the top-left corner of the browser. These offsets are necessary to properly calculate the mouse position relative to the canvas rather than its default which is relative to the browser window. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Refer to this. Hope this will be useful.
http://hacksaw.mmto.arizona.edu/src/RGraph_2010-03-27-stable/RGraph/docs/context.html